# Can I use * to find the content of obj reference?

Tags: java, reference

The code cannot be compiled:

```
public class TestBench_1_2_Answer {
    public static void reverse(char* str) {
    }
}
```

The error is：

> Syntax error on token "*", delete this token

Comment: Read a very very basic tutorial please.

Comment: I think we're getting our C and our Java confused here...

Comment: @nikpon No, that's a Java question.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with *  with type in java?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Now nobody said it was Java but the project is in C and wrong version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you don't have **pointers**, you pass the String.
This will work:

```
public class TestBench_1_2_Answer {
    public static void reverse(String str) {
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun: the `str` itself is the reference to the object passed

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
public class TestBench_1_2_Answer {
    public static void reverse(char str) {
    }
}
```

what are you trying to achieve with *  with type in java

if your intention is to reverse the string

```
 public class TestBench_1_2_Answer {
        public static void reverse(String str) {
           new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JoshM `d` to `b`?  `if(str == 'd') return 'b'; else if(str == 'b') return 'd'; else //throw an exception` And I guess this code is incomplete because chars like `I`, `w`, etc. could return themselves.

Comment: @nhgrif Really? I was under the impression that he wanted to reverse the order of characters in a `String`. Apparently not...